# angular2-cli : cannot import bootstrap.css in index.html

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have created this demo project in angular2 using angular-cli.
but when I am trying to include bootstrap using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

it's showing me below error:

> GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

But this works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
```

if I moved my bootstrap css to the directory where index.html is.

I cant use bootstrap in my application.
I know its pretty simple but its not working for me.
I used to include bootstrap in my previous applications using same approach and it worked for me.
When i am using bootstrap through CDN links its working fine.
my bootstrap file is located in same directory as path.
any inputs?

Comment: can you give a screenshot inside of your node_module's folder. where is your index.html is sitting ?